# Have bootstrap image height be constrained by another column, maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a reusable element using bootstrap which will work with images of varying aspect ratio. In order for this to work I need to crop the right side of the image
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRSwu.png)

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card shadow h-100">
      <div class="card-body-article">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-3 d-flex align-content-center">
            <div class="article-img-crop">
              <img class="article-img" src="https://images.amcnetworks.com/blogs.amctv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bb-s5-skinny-pete-interview-560.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card-title">Test</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="text-muted text-right">03/05/2020 12:52pm</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="text-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras gravida lectus eu elit maximus rhoncus. Vivamus vitae enim in felis consequat efficitur a quis dui. Aenean id tristique dui, in finibus dui. Etiam ut nunc lobortis, tempor odio ut, ornare metus. Donec convallis tincidunt velit. Nullam ipsum est, condimentum quis nunc quis, sollicitudin condimentum orci. Nunc vehicula porttitor porttitor. Duis et augue vestibulum, iaculis eros vitae, lacinia urna.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.article-img-crop {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.35rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.35rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ce3mxnLp/

The problem is that the element in its current form will take the height of the source image. I want the element height to be determined by the amount of text, while the image should scale (maintaining aspect ratio) and just cut off a varying portion of the right side. Is this possible given that bootstrap columns are flexboxes? I can't seem to use the height of a column to constrain the properties of another element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer for image, set **width** and **height** on **image**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .article-img-crop {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.35rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.35rem;
  left:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card shadow h-100">
      <div class="card-body-article">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-3 d-flex align-content-center">
            <div class="article-img-crop">
              <img class="article-img" src="https://images.amcnetworks.com/blogs.amctv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bb-s5-skinny-pete-interview-560.jpg" style="width:300px;height:100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card-title">Test</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="text-muted text-right">03/05/2020 12:52pm</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="text-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras gravida lectus eu elit maximus rhoncus. Vivamus vitae enim in felis consequat efficitur a quis dui. Aenean id tristique dui, in finibus dui. Etiam ut nunc lobortis, tempor odio ut, ornare metus. Donec convallis tincidunt velit. Nullam ipsum est, condimentum quis nunc quis, sollicitudin condimentum orci. Nunc vehicula porttitor porttitor. Duis et augue vestibulum, iaculis eros vitae, lacinia urna.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xj408apo/

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I'm trying to achieve. I need the image to scale as the text content grows. Your solution hardcodes the width and scales the height to match based on aspect ratio.